# Parser Error Message: 'FCR2.abs' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.Page'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem please?

This is the Parser Error When I Run the Application:

```
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: 'FCR2.abs' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.Page'.

Source Error: 

Line 1:  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="404.aspx.cs" Inherits="FCR2.abs" %>
Line 2:  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
Line 3:  </asp:Content>


Source File: /404.aspx    Line: 1 `enter code here`
```

This is my 404.aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="404.aspx.cs" Inherits="FCR2.abs" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h2>Page Not Found</h1>
    <p>You have come here by mistake or the page you are trying to view is no longer availible.</p>
    <p>Go back to the <a href="Default.aspx">Home Page</a></p>
</asp:Content>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

This is the 404.aspx.cs code:

```
namespace FCR2
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

This is the 404.aspx.designer.cs code:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated. 
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace FCR2 {


    public partial class abs {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using the same class names for that part of your code.

If you are using abs, you need to rename this like that:

```
namespace FCR2 
{     
   public partial class abs : System.Web.UI.Page     
   {         
      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)              {          
      }     
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure as what you are trying over here

```
public partial class abs {
    }
```

This is defined as partial class and is not inhesriting for Page (as it happens for `WebForm1`)

and your inherits points out to `Inherits="FCR2.abs"` which i believe should be `WebForm1` instead of `abs`

Try right click `Convert to Web Application` and that should generate the proper designer file for you

Comment: thanks guys. cant make a vote up because i dont have any reputation :)